# Access variable outside request cheerio's fucntion

Tags: javascript, callback, cheerio

I'm facing an issue for accessing my variable outside the request function of cheerio's library.

Here is my code simplified for better understanding :

```
var fullDragonInfo = {};

dragonsInfo.forEach(dragon => {

    request(`url=${dragon.name}`, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('tr').each(function (i) {
                let childrenElement = $(this).children('td').children('font');

                breedingList.push({
                    'parent_1': {
                        'name': childrenElement.eq(0).text(),
                        'color': childrenElement.eq(0).attr('color')
                    },
                    'parent_2': {
                        'name': childrenElement.eq(1).text(),
                        'color': childrenElement.eq(1).attr('color')
                    },
                    'Tokens': childrenElement.last().text()
                });

            });

            Object.assign(fullDragonInfo, {
                [dragon.name]: {
                    'type': dragon.type,
                    'tier': dragon.tier,
                    'class': dragon.class,
                    'breedable_level': dragon.breedable_level,
                    'breeds_combination': breedingList
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

fs.writeFile("finalData.json", JSON.stringify(fullDragonInfo));
```

So my output file `finalData.json` is showing an empty object. But if I do a console log inside the callback function the data is here.

So I assume the problem is that I'm not being able to access my variable outside the callback but I have no clue about how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the request happens asynchronously, but you write your file synchronously, it's being written before any of your requests have returned. You need to wait for your requests to finish before writing the file.

If you can use promises, that might be better. But just counting your requests will involve less modifications to your code as it is now:

```
var fullDragonInfo = {};
var callbackCount = 0;

dragonsInfo.forEach(dragon => {

    callbackCount++;

    request(`url=${dragon.name}`, function (error, response, html) {

        callbackCount--;

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('tr').each(function (i) {
                let childrenElement = $(this).children('td').children('font');

                breedingList.push({
                    'parent_1': {
                        'name': childrenElement.eq(0).text(),
                        'color': childrenElement.eq(0).attr('color')
                    },
                    'parent_2': {
                        'name': childrenElement.eq(1).text(),
                        'color': childrenElement.eq(1).attr('color')
                    },
                    'Tokens': childrenElement.last().text()
                });

            });

            Object.assign(fullDragonInfo, {
                [dragon.name]: {
                    'type': dragon.type,
                    'tier': dragon.tier,
                    'class': dragon.class,
                    'breedable_level': dragon.breedable_level,
                    'breeds_combination': breedingList
                }
            });
        }

        if (callbackCount === 0) {
            fs.writeFile("finalData.json", JSON.stringify(fullDragonInfo));
        }
    });
});
```

By counting up each request you make, and then removing a count each time you get a response, you'll know that if the count is zero again, all the requests must have finished. So at the end of each request, we check if it was the last one to finish, and if so, it's safe to write your data to the file.